# Logging into Facebook from any apps , but through a browser

Tags: applications, facebook

Problem:

So, my problem here is there's an app (*for convenient reason we don't talk about the name of the app*) that when I login to the app, it will always be directed to the Facebook that I have installed. The Facebook itself wasn't installed by default, so that I had to install it from Play Store, that means by default (*without any help*), this Facebook **can't** be **disabled**.

I'm talking about a system app or whatever its name. I.e. the system app usually has this button below, my phone with android 8.1 has this button on the Facebook, but my phone with android 11 doesn't

[image]

[image]

The thing is, whenever I login, it will fail to be connected to Facebook, please see the screenshot below:

[image]

So, somehow, I need the app to be always directed to the browser instead. First of all, of course, I need to login to Facebook in a browser, afterwards I want, when I login to the app, it will be directed to the browser that I've logged in, instead of to the installed Facebook app, which will usually happen.

How to do that? I've contacted the developer about this problem but haven't got answered. I'm sure it's possible, because when I uninstall Facebook, it will be directed to the browser. But I **don't want** to uninstall my Facebook. Is it possible to be done without root?

I'm thinking of using **Appcloner**. This app has a feature directing the app to web.

[image]

I'm not a fan of cloning app, though. I just don't like it. Do you have any ideas as to how to solve this problem without cloning the app, uninstalling my Facebook, rooting?

Comment: Unpack apk, search and replace the string and repack Also there's an app that can change link behaviour

Comment: Thanks, which app exactly? Other than the app cloner?

Comment: While this might work, mind to explain how that's done? Not all our users are tech-savvy. While on it, please also include what this means to app updates.

Comment: @user516076 does WLFX's suggestion work?

Comment: @AndrewT. Honestly I've no Idea. I've searched on YT and Googled all the possibility apps but I haven't found how. My best way to do this, though, it isn't what I want, is uninstalling Facebook.